# List.Find and CompoareTo to get the lowest value

Tags: list, find, compareto

How would I write Find() to get the lowest value in a List?  Is it possible? Thanks!

```
class testClass
{ int value; }

List<testClass> newList;

newList.Find((a,b) => a.value.CompareTo(b.value)); // test for -1???
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the language that you are using. This kind of functionality is a little different (syntactically) with each programming language.

Answer (score 0):

In virtually any language that has generic data structures, you will almost always find some sort of `Comparable` interface that allows you to specify how to compare two of your objects. In Java, it is the [`java.lang.Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface; in C#, it is the [`System.IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10bh446d) class. In order to answer your question, **read the documentation on the specific interface for the language that you are coding in**. That should give you enough information to get started. If it isn't, you probably need to take a beginning course in programming or read a beginning programming book.